# Poisson process Probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-distribution

If I assume that $\{N(t)=: t \ge 0\}$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.  For $0<s<t$, how would I find the $\Pr\{N(t)>N(s)\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $P(N(t)-N(s)>0) \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda(t-s))$ which is related to the independent increments property.

if $M \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda(t-s))$, $P(M>0) = 1-P(M=0) = 1-e^{\lambda(t-s)}$

Comment: So I can say since they have independent increments, than I can look at $P(N(t)-N(s)>0)$ ~ $Poisson (\lambda(t-s))$ which would correspond to the probability of 1-$e^{\lambda(t-s)}$?

Comment: Yeah basically, you're looking at the chances that *at least* one arrival occurs between s and t.